# Unable to get Circles to render on react-leaflet map after API call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-leaflet

I am working on a project to display user-reported sightings to a react leaflet map. Currently, I am just trying to set up my SightingMap component to make an API request to fetch sightings data and then use that data to create Circle components and render them on the map.

I am using Redux for state management and am using a functional component with hooks approach. I have been able to make the API request (using axios) and I can see that the data is being populated in the redux store via redux dev tools. **The problem is that the Circles are not being rendered to the map, so I just see a blank leaflet map with no Circles.**

In SightingMap.js, I am using the useEffect() hook to dispatch the fetchSightings() action creator which calls the API. For now, I just have dummy data being returned. Then I am calling the renderCircles() function with the data that is extracted from the redux store.

```
import { Map, TileLayer, Circle } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { FETCH_SIGHTINGS } from '../actions/types';
import './SightingMap.css';
import '../api/sightings';
import sightingsAPI from '../api/sightings';

const SightingMap = () => {
    const fetchedSightings = useSelector(state => state.sightings.fetchedSightings);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const fetchSightings = () => async dispatch => {
        const response = await sightingsAPI.get('/sightings');
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_SIGHTINGS,
            payload: response.data
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchSightings());
    }, [dispatch]);


    const renderCircles = sightings => {
        sightings.map(sighting => <Circle key={sighting.id} center={[sighting.lat, sighting.lng]} radius={sighting.radius} />);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Map className="map" center={[51.5, -0.07]} zoom={2} preferCanvas={true} onClick={e => console.log(`you clicked the map at ${e.latlng}`)}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                {renderCircles(fetchedSightings)}
            </Map> 
        </div>
        
    );
}

export default SightingMap;
```

Here is the reducer code:

```
import { FETCH_SIGHTINGS } from '../actions/types'

export default (state = {fetchedSightings: []}, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_SIGHTINGS:
            return {
                ...state, 
                fetchedSightings: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And lastly here you can see the response from the api:

```
{
    "sightings": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "lat": 23,
            "lng": 20,
            "radius": 350
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "lat": 51.508262,
            "lng": -0.076132,
            "radius": 200
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "lat": 35.903977, 
            "lng": -438.903476,
            "radius": 350
        }
    ]
}
```

If there is any additional information I could provide, let me know.

Comment: With a quick look I would say that you need to return what is inside `renderCircles` as a first thing to do: `return sightings.map(sighting => <Circle key={sighting.id} center={[sighting.lat, sighting.lng]} radius={sighting.radius} />);
`

Comment: This solved it, can't believe I missed that. Thanks.